# How to create custom view with rounded border in Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

Hi,

I'm trying to understand how to make custom view (with green background) on Android like represented on attached image. Please suggest, should I use Path for this or something else?

[image: attached image]

Comment: Can you post your layout xml file so that I can take a quick look?

Comment: Hi ap6491, I have not started write a code, because have no idea how to start even and that's why asking any suggestion. But, if it is correct I'm going to start with extending my custom view from View class.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point would be http://tips.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-layout-rounded-corner-border/ . Then you can play with the attribute values to get the desired background. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have two good options for accomplishing this.

## Bitmap

Create the desired image in Photoshop, Gimp or something similar. Export it as a png file then import it as a [bitmap resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap) into your Android application.

This is by far the simpler and faster of the two methods, but here are two significant problems. First, you should [supply bitmaps for each screen density bucket](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html). Second, each bitmap resource you add increases the install size of your app. This can get out of hand quickly.

## Path

As you mentioned in your question, you can draw the desired shape directly onto a canvas using a `Path`. More specifically, you'll use the `cubicTo()` method to create bezier curves.

I recommend using your image editor's "path" tool to learn how the control points affect the curve. Once you've drawn the shape in the image editor, write down the coordinates for every point on your path as well as the corresponding control points. Then do a little math to convert the points to ratios of the image's overall width and height.

You can implement the shape in your app as a `View` or as a `Drawable`. In either case, you'll be drawing to a `Canvas`. The important step will be to set up the path by multiplying the ratios with the size of your drawing area. After you draw the fancy edge, be sure to draw the straight edges via `lineTo()` and to close the shape with `close()`.

Comment: thank you for detailed explanation of both options. After that I found some articles about drawing in Android and have created rectangle using Path, fill it with gradient, transformed top border to bezier curve, but there are a lot additional tasks that should be completed to make it desirable view, so, I decided to use Bitmap for this task for now, as it is fast and less complex (with cons. for sure) then Canvas/Path.